# Google Cloud Storage Console "You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page"

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

In last couple of days there is a strange error message in Google Cloud Storage console. 
[image: Google Storage Console]

It was operating normal for many months and suddenly this error("You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page") started to raise. Have tried to logout-login the account.

In IAM when tried to check permission it says as "OWNER" which is the top most permission. For Console is it require any special permission? Is any changes made in existing Console? How to solve this?

Comment: Dumb question, but are you sure you're looking at the right project? Maybe there are two projects: the one you own and some other one? There's a dropdown on the top.

Comment: there are more than 25 projects and all are working fine. Only this project displaying this error. And doubt as it is happening only for last 3 days. it will be better if Question is marked #dumb after analysing correctly and solving it :)

Comment: @arvindwill Brandon's saying that *his* question is dumb, not that your question is dumb.

Comment: Indeed, I meant my own question likely was dumb as you had probably already considered that. Very sorry if you read it the other way. As to the problem at hand, I am perplexed. I wonder, if you ran the command `gcloud projects get-iam-policy [PROJECT-ID]` for both this project and one that works, perhaps you'd find some important difference?

Comment: @brandon sorry for it. Will check with that command let know.